# dimple.js - sort x-axis data numerical not alphabetical

Tags: sorting, dimple.js

I have chart data for my x-axis that starts with 0 and goes up to 1200, by 100 increments.  When it displays on the chart in ascending order 0 is last, not first.  If I put leading zeros on the data then 0 is in the right spot, this makes me think that the data is being sorted alphabetically rather than numerically.

Is there a way to sort numerically?

Here is my chart:

edit--> I guess I need a better StackOverflow reputation to post an image, so you'll just have to imagine a bar chart with data on the x-axis that goes from 100 to 1200 then show the data for 0 after 1200.

Here is the code for the chart:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#idle-times-chart-container", 1000, 500);
    var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "xAxis");
    x.addOrderRule("xAxis", false);
    var y = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "yAxis");
    y.tickFormat = "%";
    chart.addSeries(["OpCode"], dimple.plot.bar);
    var myLegend = chart.addLegend(950, 50, 60, 100, "Right");
    chart.draw();
    x.titleShape.text("Idle Times");
    chart.legends = [];
    var filterValues = dimple.getUniqueValues(data, "OpCode");
    myLegend.shapes.selectAll("rect")
        .on("click", function (e) {
            var hide = false;
            var newFilters = [];
            filterValues.forEach(function (f) {
                if (f === e.aggField.slice(-1)[0]) {
                    hide = true;
                } else {
                    newFilters.push(f);
                }
            });
            if (hide) {
                d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.2);
            } else {
                newFilters.push(e.aggField.slice(-1)[0]);
                d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.8);
            }
            filterValues = newFilters;
            chart.data = dimple.filterData(data, "OpCode", filterValues);
            chart.draw(1000);
            x.titleShape.text("Idle Times");
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *should* work.  I wonder if it's a bug in v2.  Can you try using [version 1.1.5](http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v1.1.5.min.js) and seeing if that works correctly? Unfortunately the animated bars might not look great in version 1.1.5 but we can at least see if it is a bug in the code-base.

Comment: I just tried version 1.1.5 and have the same results

Comment: Strange, here's a demo of it working correctly for a simple case: http://jsbin.com/lorin/4/edit?js,output

Comment: If you change 0.4 to 0, in the first xAxis value, the problem is recreated, and that zero value is pushed past the 1014 value

Comment: Great spot, it seems zero is a special case which breaks the sorting.  I suggest you create a new issue on the GitHub pages. Interestingly 0.0 works ok so that may be a work-around for you in the meantime.

Comment: This issue was fixed in Dimple.js 2.0